# How can I conditionally map properties using Automapper based on user permissions

Tags: automapper

I am using Automapper successfully throughout my application however I have come across a particular requirement that I cannot find a solution for.

My application is an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application using Automapper 10.  What I need to do is only map some properties from the Dto to the data entity if a user has permission to edit these specific properties.  I am using a Claims Principal to store the information I need regarding the user.

In the simplest form I only want to map the property "Enabled" if the user performing the editing is an administrator.  I can check if the user is an admin based on claims but I have no idea how I let Automapper know this.

Can it be done or am I better manually map in this instance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to store the user role information in the `Items` dictionary on runtime. Then using `Condition()` you can check the role during mapping by retrieving the user role information from the same `Items` dictionary.

Mapping usage inside a controller:

```cs
var entity = mapper.Map<Entity>(dto, opts =>
{
    opts.Items["UserRole"] = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;
});
```

Mapping configuration:

```cs
CreateMap<DTO, Entity>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Enabled,
        o =>
        {
            o.Condition((s, d, sm, dt, resolutionContext) =>
            {
                return resolutionContext.Items.TryGetValue("UserRole", out var userRole)
                    && userRole.ToString() == "Admin";
            });
            o.MapFrom(s => s.Enabled);
        });
```

---

Other way is to use `ServiceCtor` from options inside a `ResolutionContext` to resolve any services required to establish user role, I will use `IHttpContextAccessor` as an example:

Mapping usage does not change at all:

```cs
var entity = mapper.Map<Entity>(dto);
```

Mapping configuration a bit more complex:

```cs
CreateMap<DTO, Entity>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Enabled,
        o =>
        {
            o.Condition((s, d, sm, dt, resolutionContext) =>
            {
                var httpContextAccessor = resolutionContext
                    .Options
                    .ServiceCtor(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;
                var userRole = httpContextAccessor
                    .HttpContext
                    .User
                    .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role)
                    ?.Value;

                return userRole == "Admin";
            });
            o.MapFrom(s => s.Enabled);
        });
```

Keep in mind that `IHttpContextAccessor` does not always return a `HttpContext`. It may be `null`. It also requires that you register it in `ConfigureServices()` in your `Startup` class:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work until I switched to o.PreCondition but then perfect.  Thanks